# ABC pdf is not working for https

Tags: abcpdf

ABCpdf is not supported the **https** images , when we generate the **pdf** we will get the cross symbols.

Please help me .

Thank You

Comment: what's an "https image"? You mean remote image accessed via http URI? Are there any errors produced in the process? Are you logged in to that website properly? Where is the [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Get the HTML. In this example I'm reading the html from a text file (for demonstration purposes)

string HTML_STRING;
var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\html.txt");
HTML_STRING = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();

//****************************************
// Create PDF
//****************************************

//Initiate the document

var theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.TextStyle.Size = 20;
theDoc.Rect.Inset(40, 55);
theDoc.Color.String = "255 255 255"; //Clear rectangle

//Add the html
int theId = theDoc.AddImageHtml(HTML_STRING);

//We now chain subsequent pages together. We stop when we reach a page which wasn't truncated

while (true)
{
theDoc.FrameRect();
if (!theDoc.Chainable(theId))
break;
theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
theId = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theId);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Set pagenumber
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

theDoc.HtmlOptions.LinkPages();

//Set the position for the page number

theDoc.Rect.String = "35 30 580 50";
theDoc.Font = theDoc.AddFont("Trebuchet");
theDoc.FontSize = 11;
int pagenumber = 1;

//flatten the pages. We can't do this until after the pages have been added because flattening will invalidate our previous ID and break the chain.

for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++)
{
theDoc.PageNumber = i;

//Add page number
//========================================

string txt = pagenumber.ToString();
theDoc.Color.String = "169 169 169"; //Dark grey text

//Positioning depends on if the page is even or odd
theDoc.VPos = 1.0;
if ((i%2) == 0)
{
//Even
theDoc.HPos = 0.01;
}
else
{
//Odd
theDoc.HPos = 0.99;
}

//Add the page number
theDoc.AddText(txt);

//Add a line above page number
theDoc.AddLine(21, 55, 590, 55);

//Flatten page
theDoc.Flatten();

//Increase the page number count
pagenumber++;

}

//==============================

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Save the pdf file
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Save the document
theDoc.Save(@"c:\pdf.pdf");

//Clear
theDoc.Clear();
```